# Flutter how to save position of the reorderables package?

Tags: flutter

i tried the reorderables package https://pub.dev/packages/reorderables
I successed to move my dashboard blocs but when I restart app, my moves are removed.

So the solution can only be a sharedpref solution.
But I dont found how to save this information

I tried to save and load newIndex but without success
I tried to save and load   List _tiles; but sharedpref can't save List

Here is my code example

```
List<Widget> _tiles;
  void _onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    setState(() {

      Widget row = _tiles.removeAt(oldIndex);
      _tiles.insert(newIndex, row);


      //prefs.setListWidget('indexList', _tiles);  not working
    //  prefs.setInt('index', newIndex );  not working


    });
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _tiles = <Widget>[
//my widget1
//my widget2
//my widget3

//my widget4
//my widget5
//my widget6

//my widget7
//my widget8
//my widget9

]
 }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {



    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
     ReorderableWrap(
     spacing: 0.0,
     runSpacing:0,
     maxMainAxisCount: 3,
     minMainAxisCount: 3,
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
      children:_tiles,

        onReorder: _onReorder,
        onNoReorder: (int index) {
          //this callback is optional
          debugPrint('${DateTime.now().toString().substring(5, 22)} reorder cancelled. index:$index');
        },
        onReorderStarted: (int index) {
          //this callback is optional
          debugPrint('${DateTime.now().toString().substring(5, 22)} reorder started: index:$index');
        }
    )
    ]
    );
  }
}
```

edit : here is Widget 1. other widget are same

```
  new Container (
        width: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 32,
        height: 160,

        child :
        new Card(
            elevation: 8,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            color: Colors.white,
            child:
            Ink(

              child: InkResponse(
                  splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory,
                  radius: 100,
                  onTap: () {

                  },
                  child:
                  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:10),
                      child:
                      new     Container(

                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        child :

                        new Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[

                            new     Container(
                              height:25,

                              child :


                              new Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[

                                    Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right, color: Colors.white, size: 15.0),

                                    Text('Planning',textAlign:TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                        fontSize: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 4),
                                    ),
                                    Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right, color: Colors.grey, size: 15.0),
                                  ]
                              ),
                            ),


                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),),
                            Icon(Icons.event_available, color:Color(0xffff9a7b), size: 70.0),


                          ],
                        ),
                      ))
              ),
            )),
      )
```

Here is my design

[image]

Edit #2

Now I tried to add my assets in the model, but I don't know how to do

```
void initState() {
    // default models list
    models = [

      Model(index: 0, new Container (
          width:90,
          height: 90,
          child :new FlareActor("assets/pierre.flr", alignment:Alignment.center, fit:BoxFit.contain, animation:"pierre")
      ), title: 'Coach'),

      Model(index: 1, new Image.asset(
        "assets/cup.png",
        width: 50,
      ), title: 'Victories'),

      Model(index: 2, icon: Icon(Icons.card_giftcard), title: 'Jeux'),
      Model(index: 3, icon: Icon(Icons.wb_sunny), title: 'Sunny'),
      Model(index: 4, icon: Icon(Icons.cloud), title: 'Cloud'),
      Model(index: 5, icon: Icon(Icons.tv), title: 'TV'),
      Model(index: 6, icon: Icon(Icons.place), title: 'Location'),
      Model(index: 8, icon: Icon(Icons.music_note), title: 'Music'),
      // More customization
      Model(
          index: 7,
          icon: Icon(Icons.event_available, color: Color(0xffff9a7b)),
          title: 'Planning'),
    ];
    config();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: ***SharedPreferences*** can save a list of string too, [This tutorial](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/using-sharedpreferences-in-flutter-251755f07127) shows how to save/fetch from SharedPreferences.

Comment: _tiles is only a list on Widget and index an int, but I don't know if i'm look right... I don't know if it's even possible with this plugin

Comment: honestly, I didn't work with this package, I don't know what is your widget like, but if it is possible, instead of storing bunch of widgets, use model, and each time make a widget from that model, I'll write it for you, but I need an example of your widget.

Comment: thank you I have edit my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This solution isn't a good one and I don't like it, but it works :D**

**I really appreciate it if anyone would refer a better one**

Maybe for this project, it's good to use DB instead of `SharedPreferences` but here I used `SharedPreferences`.

The question is how to save the order of some widget(each time on reordering, the order of widget changes and we want to save the order of them, after restarting the app the saved order should be fetched).

`SharedPreferences` can also save a list of string, so what I did here was:

In the beginning, there should be a default list, that contains the initial order of widget's of the app.

Because widgets are somehow the same and only some of their info is different, I decided to define a model and work with models, instead of a whole complicated widget, I mean when I want to remove or change indexes I do it for a list of  models rather than a list of widgets.

Here I supposed the model only contains a title, I also defined an index for it, so all I do is that when I reorder the widget, it reorders the list of models, to save the order, I save the index of models in any order they are now,

for example, if the initial order was [0, 1, 2, 3] let's say after reordering it's now [3, 0, 1, 2], I save this order, and for the next boot, I fetch the saved order([3, 0, 1, 2]) and then reorder the default list based on this fetched order.

Another solution would be to change the model's index and then show an ordered list of models based on their index.

Here is the code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:reorderables/reorderables.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Page(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageState createState() => _PageState();
}

class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  SharedPreferences prefs;

  List<Model> models;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // default models list
    models = [
      Model(index: 0, title: 'Item 0'),
      Model(index: 1, title: 'Item 1'),
      Model(index: 2, title: 'Item 2'),
      Model(index: 3, title: 'Item 3'),
    ];
    config();
    super.initState();
  }

  void config() async {
    // Here we reset the default model based on  saved order
    await SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((pref) {
      prefs = pref;
      List<String> lst = pref.getStringList('indexList');

      List<Model> list = [];
      if (lst != null && lst.isNotEmpty) {
        list = lst
            .map(
              (String indx) => models
                  .where((Model item) => int.parse(indx) == item.index)
                  .first,
            )
            .toList();
        models = list;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  void _onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) async {
    Model row = models.removeAt(oldIndex);
    models.insert(newIndex, row);
    setState(() {
      prefs.setStringList(
          'indexList', models.map((m) => m.index.toString()).toList());
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReorderableWrap(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        direction: Axis.vertical,
        spacing: 0.0,
        runSpacing: 0,
        maxMainAxisCount: 3,
        minMainAxisCount: 3,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        children: models
            .map((m) => Card(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text('${m.index} - ${m.title}'),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                  ),
                ))
            .toList(),
        onReorder: _onReorder,
        onNoReorder: (int index) {
          //this callback is optional
          debugPrint('${DateTime.now().toString().substring(5, 22)} ' +
              'reorder cancelled. index:$index');
        },
        onReorderStarted: (int index) {
          //this callback is optional
          debugPrint('${DateTime.now().toString().substring(5, 22)} ' +
              'reorder started: index:$index');
        });
  }
}

class Model {
  int index;
  String title;

  Model({this.index, this.title});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$index : $title';
  }
}
```

## Changes After Edit to the main question:

This version is based on the editing to the main question, I decided to keep the first answer unchanged because it's a more simple version and may help another viewer.

For the new model, as far as I could get, it has an icon, title, and an onTap functionality, I changed the model to have icon and title, but for the onTap, I wrote my own card version that gets a model and onTap functionality, I could add onTap to the model, but I thought it's better for future use or to use in other places, so I separated the onTap from the model, I also chose `Icon` for the model, it could be `IconData` (benefit of `IconData` is that you can choose customization for each icon and etc).

On my Card version (MyCard), I simply used a `GestureDetector` and `Card` to simulate the taps and card.

I wrote a `FakePage` that gets a model and if you Tap on each card it navigates to this page and shows some message based on the received model.

To clean the previously saved model in `SharedPreferences`, you should comment the part that fetches models order in `config()` and on the next refresh, you should uncomment it again.

Here is the new version of code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:reorderables/reorderables.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Page(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageState createState() => _PageState();
}

class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  SharedPreferences prefs;

  List<Model> models;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // default models list
    models = [
      Model(index: 0, icon: Icon(Icons.people), title: 'Coach'),
      Model(index: 1, icon: Icon(Icons.wb_incandescent), title: 'Victories'),
      Model(index: 2, icon: Icon(Icons.card_giftcard), title: 'Jeux'),
      Model(index: 3, icon: Icon(Icons.wb_sunny), title: 'Sunny'),
      Model(index: 4, icon: Icon(Icons.cloud), title: 'Cloud'),
      Model(index: 5, icon: Icon(Icons.tv), title: 'TV'),
      Model(index: 6, icon: Icon(Icons.place), title: 'Location'),
      Model(index: 8, icon: Icon(Icons.music_note), title: 'Music'),
      // More customization
      Model(
          index: 7,
          icon: Icon(Icons.event_available, color: Color(0xffff9a7b)),
          title: 'Planning'),
    ];
    config();
    super.initState();
  }

  void config() async {
    // Here we reset the default model based on  saved order
    await SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((pref) {
      prefs = pref;
      List<String> lst = pref.getStringList('indexList');

      List<Model> list = [];
      if (lst != null && lst.isNotEmpty) {
        list = lst
            .map(
              (String indx) => models
                  .where((Model item) => int.parse(indx) == item.index)
                  .first,
            )
            .toList();
        models = list;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  void _onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) async {
    Model row = models.removeAt(oldIndex);
    models.insert(newIndex, row);
    setState(() {
      prefs.setStringList(
          'indexList', models.map((m) => m.index.toString()).toList());
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReorderableWrap(
        spacing: 0.0,
        runSpacing: 0,
        maxMainAxisCount: 3,
        minMainAxisCount: 3,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        children: <Widget>[
          MyCard(
            model: models[0],
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => FakePage(model: models[0]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          MyCard(
            model: models[1],
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => FakePage(model: models[1]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          MyCard(
            model: models[2],
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => FakePage(model: models[2]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          MyCard(
            model: models[3],
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => FakePage(model: models[3]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          MyCard(
            model: models[4],
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => FakePage(model: models[4]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          MyCard(
            model: models[5],
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => FakePage(model: models[5]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          MyCard(
            model: models[6],
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => FakePage(model: models[6]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          MyCard(
            model: models[7],
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => FakePage(model: models[7]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          MyCard(
            model: models[8],
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => FakePage(model: models[8]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        onReorder: _onReorder,
        onNoReorder: (int index) {
          //this callback is optional
          debugPrint('${DateTime.now().toString().substring(5, 22)} ' +
              'reorder cancelled. index:$index');
        },
        onReorderStarted: (int index) {
          //this callback is optional
          debugPrint('${DateTime.now().toString().substring(5, 22)} ' +
              'reorder started: index:$index');
        });
  }
}

// ---------------------- Model --------------------------
class Model {
  int index;
  String title;
  Icon icon;
  Model({this.index, this.title, this.icon});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$index : $title';
  }
}

// ------------------------ MyCard ----------------------------
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Model model;
  final void Function() onTap;

  const MyCard({Key key, this.onTap, @required this.model})
      : assert(model != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Card(
        elevation: 8.0,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        child: _child(width),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _child(double width) {
    return Container(
      width: width / 4,
      height: width / 3,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  model.title,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                  ),
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                  color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                  size: 15.0,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                child: model.icon,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// ----------------------- FAKE PAGE ---------------------------
class FakePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Model model;
  const FakePage({Key key, this.model}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You Clicked on Card : ${model.title}',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24.0),
              child: Icon(
                model.icon.icon,
                size: 70.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention it, There's also a  [ReorderableListView](https://youtu.be/3fB1mxOsqJE) that you can use instead of `ReorderableWrap`.

Comment: Thank you for this exemple, it's work but I have trouble to customize the model to match with my design. I have some time assets, icon, asset and in all my container when I tap I call a widget. So I don't know how to customize model with various sources. I edit post with my design

Comment: You're wellcome, Happy it helped. I added new code.

Comment: Wow thank you for your help !! you rock ! Just a last question, I don't sussecced to add asset or flare to the model. I upload my post.

Comment: Happy it helped, It seems assets are shown and used the same and the only difference is the path, so you can change icon in model to include the path of the asset, then in `MyCard`, have all these `container` and `FlareActor` , then set the received model’s path to the widgets. `Model contains: index, title, asset`

Comment: Thank you I don't know if I understood or was misunderstood, but model can"t display different source ? I have one block with icon, one block with asset and one block with flare, I don't see or understand how to display all in one model ^^ I'm really uncomfortable with this coding mode :)

Comment: I will simplify and change icon and asset by all flare mode :)

Comment: Sorry it was my fault, I thought you want to replace icon with assets, models can be anything, I usually define models for API, DB or some related widgets. So this model can have title, icon, asset, key, index,....

Comment: You can have different model or simply With one model but check if the value aren’t null, they should show something, I guess defining model depends on the project you are doing and to see if it worse it or not.

Comment: It's ok now with design, but I have trouble with Fakepage example, If I change block disposition the link to my fake pages wasn't changed. For exemple I have Fakepage in the index0 if I move block to the second index My fakepage don't move with my block

Comment: It's OK :) I found an ugly solution ^^ I listen each index from the list and call the page of the index of the Card tapped. ALL IS WORKING !! thank you for all !!

Comment: Sorry I didn’t get it, page info doesn’t update with tapping different block(model)? Page depends on the model it gets. If first block is for example’Planning’ , shouldn’t it remain despite of its location?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I change your fake page route by my block and I havn't see the subtilities ^^ your are right :)

Comment: If it’s not Ok, I’ll be happy to help, we can move this discussion to chat.